# How to put current content into panel with margins?

Tags: html, css

How can I add a background and put current content of the web page in the panel (with margins) as it shown [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/1051180-Bills-Bills-Bills)?

Is it possible to do this trick with minimal changes of CSS stylesheet and html code?

Comment: Anything is possible when you include actual code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course possible.

1. Set `background` for `<body>`.
2. Set `width` to your outermost element and `margin: auto;`

If you shared any code, more specific explanation would be possible.

here is example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kbqcsgj8/